# Android Gridview - change child layout direction to down then across?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I apologise if this is a bit of a noob question.  Also, I googled extensively and couldn't find an answer. My primary language is C#, just begun learning to program for Android.

By default it seems that a GridView lays out its child controls from left to right then down like so:

- 1 2 3 4 5
- 6 7 8 9 0
- a b c d e

Is it possible to get a GridView to lay it controls out down then across like this?:

- 1 4 7 0 c
- 2 5 8 a d
- 3 6 9 b e

I have a fixed number of array items that I wish to display so it I can just add the items to the appropriate spot in the array and it will display like this.  However I wanted to know if there is a simpler way to get the GV to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing what you want to achieve is to use the position system instead.

You just take your GridView and then getChildAt(). The int you are using is the position of the child. Then you just use the int of the position.

01234

56789

Remember that GridView allways start at 0 and not 1.

Code example to get the child number 8:

```
View theChild =gridView.getChildAt(7);
```

If you want to get something inside the Child you use this instead:

```
SomeView theChild = (SomeView)gridView.getChildAt(7);
```